# LaTeX snippets from Math.SE look like gibberish in the Stack Exchange hot questions list

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stackexchange, globalinbox

This is what it looks like on Math.SE:

[image]

This is what it looks like in the SE hot topics list:

[image]

Comment: Well, I guess they don't want to embed MathJax on all sites that don't really need it. What would you prefer to have it look like?

Comment: @slhck Filter it from the list, or include it as needed.

Comment: While I agree its ugly, I don't really see a good solution for this problem without adding the overhead of MathJax on every site

Comment: I doubt it'll be fixed - http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99030/133693

Comment: Easy fix: Detect Math stuff in titles and filter it from the popular question list if it's not enabled. If you can't display it, discard it.

Comment: @DanielBeck That fix is too general. Sometimes you want to display raw LaTeX code rather than preview it, for example any question about LaTeX might include LaTeX code that should be shown as is. That is the reason why http://tex.stackexchange.com and http://stackoverflow.com lacks MathJax. Note that a question about a LaTeX question is hard to programmatically distinguish math questions from question about LaTeX because the LaTeX questions might be about expressing certain math with LaTeX.

Comment: @N.N. True. I'm sure glad I just report it and don't have to fix it :-)

Comment: @DanielBeck I am not sure whether it is even worth fixing. If a title includes a LaTeX code it is probably quite easy to read even if you know little LaTeX, as in the example you provide, so you will not gain much in fixing it (complex LaTeX expression won't fit in titles). Also, as pointed out in the MSO link above MathJax requires massive resources to run and it would probably mean that the inbox gets slower which would be against its purpose of efficiently informing of new things.

Comment: @N.N. instead of this information getting buried in comments, consider adding an actual answer post. (:

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff Done!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you want to display raw LaTeX code rather than preview it, for example any question about LaTeX might include LaTeX code that should be shown as is. That is the reason why http://tex.stackexchange.com and http://stackoverflow.com lacks MathJax. Note that a question about LaTeX question is hard to programmatically distinguish from a math question because LaTeX questions might also contain math expressed in LaTeX.

I am not sure whether it is even worth fixing. If a title includes a LaTeX code it is probably quite easy to read even if you know little LaTeX, as in the example you provide, so you will not gain much in fixing it (and complex LaTeX expressions won't fit in question titles). Also, [as pointed out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97938/any-chance-of-mathjax-in-chat/99030#99030) MathJax requires massive resources to run and it would probably mean that the inbox gets slower which would be against its purpose of efficiently informing of new things.